# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in Codeigniter3

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to store a array into database(SQL Server),
 in that array I am getting some values from UI,
 and some values fetched from Model. 
Here my problem is with second one only... The values coming from UI is getting inserted, 
but  the values coming from model are in object notation....
It can't store into a single variable...so that the data is not even store into database... 
and it raises the error

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Here is my code...

Model

```
public function getCustcode($customer)
{
 return $query = $MainDB->query("SELECT custcode from CRM_CustomerEvents_View  where custname = '".$customer."'")->row();
}
```

Controller:

```
public function addEvent()
    {        
        $name               = $this->input->post("name",TRUE);
        $start_date         = $this->input->post("start_date", TRUE);
        $end_date           = $this->input->post("end_date", TRUE);
        $customer           = $this->input->post("customer",TRUE);
        $custcode           = $this->Calendarmodel->getCustcode($customer);

        $tranno             = $this->input->post("transno",TRUE);
        $leadid             = $this->Calendarmodel->getLeadID($tranno);
}



$data = array(
            "title"       => $name,                          
            "start_event" => $start_date,                 
            "end_event"   => $end_date,                   
            "custcode"    => $custcode,   
            "Leadid"      => $leadid,   
             );
```

It raises the error

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

then I changed like this

```
$data = array(
            "title"       => $name,                          
            "start_event" => $start_date,                  
            "end_event"   => $end_date,
           "custcode"    => $custcode[0]['custcode'],     //'100287',//
            "Leadid"      => $leadid[0]['Leadid']         //'10070'//
             );
```

It generates the error:

> Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

If I use `json_encode($custcode)` in static way(to test) and it gives me the data as:

```
"{"custcode":"100287"}"
```

Please, can anyone give any solution to handle this object data coming from Model...

Comment: Print the result of `var_dump($custcode);`

Comment: It gives me the output as follows                                                                                     C:\wamp\www\CRM_Dev5\application\controllers\Calendar.php:163:
object(stdClass)[20]
  public 'custcode' => string '100287' (length=6)
C:\wamp\www\CRM_Dev5\application\controllers\Calendar.php:164:
object(stdClass)[21]
  public 'Leadid' => string '10070' (length=5)
An Error Was Encountered
Unable to load the requested file: Calendar_view.php

Comment: var_dump() is not worked for me sir... Can you give me any alternative solution?

Comment: I want to store id of a field in database...But I have to show customer name in UI

Comment: Did you solved your problem?

Comment: No Sir... Kindly help me

Comment: Change please this strings as `(array)$this->Calendarmodel->getCustcode($customer);` and `(array)$this->Calendarmodel->getLeadID($tranno);`. And use your second `$data`. Should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you need to convert `stdObject` into `array` by simply adding `(array)` before `stdObject`.

It should looks like:

```
$custcode = (array)$this->Calendarmodel->getCustcode($customer); 
$leadid   = (array)$this->Calendarmodel->getLeadID($tranno);
```

And use your second `$data`(try `$custcode['custcode']` and `$leadid['Leadid']`). Should help.